# Are there any scheduler to shcedule our tasks on google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

How to schedule compute instances/VM start/stop and backup of instances/VM 
Do we have any scheduler in google cloud or provided by third-party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kubernetes and jenkins you can deploy a container (most likely triggered by cron) then shut it down or back it up on some interval.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kube-jenkins-imager

You can apparently bundle your app and configuration into an immutable custom image for improved boot time and reliability:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automated-build-images-with-jenkins-kubernetes

But no handy start/stop gui at the moment it seems.

I would like a tool to : at every (x) am/pm; spin up debian with my app, start node with pm2, send out messages, spin down debian into immutable "archive" on disk.  save money by not leaving it on all day.  Programming the infrastructure is more difficult than programming the app from my perspective, atm, but it definitely seems like a great opportunity to save time and/or make money by creating such a "streamlined gui" for this.